# Undefined reference to sbuf functions on FreeBSD

Tags: c, linker, clang, freebsd, undefined-reference

#### What happened to my sbuf(9)?

This is my program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sbuf.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    struct sbuf * sb;
    sb = sbuf_new_auto();
    return 0;
}
```

When I complie my program with `clang -v test.c` I get:

> ```
> FreeBSD clang version 3.4.1 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot1-final 208032) 20140512
> Target: i386-unknown-freebsd10.3
> Thread model: posix
> Selected GCC installation: 
>  "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple i386-unknown-freebsd10.3 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name test.c -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu i486 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4.1 -fdebug-compilation-dir /usr/home/0mp/g/freebsd/contrib/openbsm/bin/bsmconv -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 170 -mstackrealign -fobjc-runtime=gnustep -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /tmp/test-fc3a72.o -x c test.c
> clang -cc1 version 3.4.1 based upon LLVM 3.4.1 default target i386-unknown-freebsd10.3
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4.1/include"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
>  /usr/include/clang/3.4.1
>  /usr/include
> End of search list.
>  "/usr/bin/ld" --eh-frame-hdr -dynamic-linker /libexec/ld-elf.so.1 --hash-style=both --enable-new-dtags -m elf_i386_fbsd -o a.out /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/crti.o /usr/lib/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib /tmp/test-fc3a72.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/crtend.o /usr/lib/crtn.o
> /tmp/test-fc3a72.o: In function `main':
> test.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `sbuf_new'
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

#### Notes

- The compiler shows me the errors and warnings for sbuf functions as well so it knows how `sys/sbuf.h` looks like.
- I use FreeBSD 10.3 RELEASE i386.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -lsbuf in your compile command?

Comment: That's a shame I couldn't find it in the manual and on the iInternet. How was I supposed to guess it? Is there a rule or a place where I can check whether a header requires a `-labc` option?

Comment: nothing that I can see right away but a pro tip: You see things failing in "undefined reference" fashion than you got your declairs (from .h) but are still missing the definition (lib).

Comment: That's what I found online - _you lack some `-l`_. However I wasn't able to find the one for sbuf(9). Thanks!

Comment: Good. now, I'd go to /usr/lib/ and do strings to find out where the missing symbol is. Hope that helps.